# how to make a list of posts titles in django

Tags: python, django, listview, django-queryset, posts

I am creating a blog web app with django where i want to make a list which contains only titles of the posts. 
i wanna make two lists namely

1. Latest posts
2. All posts

In Latest posts , i wanna list out titles of the posts created recently.Means post created at last should be in first place of the list. simple

In All Posts , i want to list out titles of all posts in ascending order. 
i am not sure how to do it.

Here is my code goes.....

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView , ListView , DetailView
from .models import home_blog_model
from .forms import create_post

class home_view(ListView):
    model = home_blog_model
    template_name = "home.html"
    context_object_name = "posts"


def detail_view(request , pk):
    obj = home_blog_model.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {"obj":obj}

    return render(request , "detail.html" , context)

def create_post_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = create_post(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect("/home/")

    else:
        form = create_post()
    return render(request , "create_post.html" , {"form":form})
```

home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
    <img src="{% static 'hori.jpg' %}" style="margin-top: 50px;margin-left: 250px;width: 60%">



    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;margin-left: 320px;margin-right: 20px">
        {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="container" style="width: 300px;box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);transition: 0.3s;width: 100%;padding: 0px;">



                    <div class="card" style="height: 200px;padding: 12px;" onclick="location.href='{% url 'detail' post.id %}'">
                        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                        <div class="card-body">{{ post.summary }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
<style>
    .card:hover { box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class home_blog_model(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView , LogoutView
urlpatterns = [

    path("" , views.home_view.as_view() , name="blog-home"),
    path("posts/<int:pk>/" , views.detail_view , name="detail"),
    path("admin/login/" , LoginView.as_view(template_name="admin-login.html") , name="admin-login"),
    path("admin/logout/" , LogoutView.as_view() , name="admin-logout"),
    path("admin/post/create/" , views.create_post_view , name="create_post"),
]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is wrong with this code? What doesn't work?

Comment: Put your url.py too please, also error msg. Would be better

Comment: There is no problem . i want to create a list of posts by title name like index and i am not sure how to do it.

Comment: i added the urls.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dictsortreversed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsortreversed) for latest posts. For example:

```
# top 5 posts
{% for post in posts|dictsortreversed:"id"|slice:"5" %}
     {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

In this way you can have posts in ascending order (like the implementation of your code) and reversed order in same template without adding anything in view. [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) was added for slicing the list for 5 objects.

Comment: worked like a charm. thank you buddy always appreciate it.

Comment: happy to help :)